# Why has Entity Framework added '...Id' field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been working through a tutorial on Udemy and seem to have made a mistake somewhere. In one model EF seems to have added an additional property as a foreign key. Here's the model:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        public byte GenreId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        public DateTime? ReleasedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime? AddedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's the migration EF generated from that:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Movies",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        GenreId = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                        Genre_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Genres", t => t.Genre_Id)
                .Index(t => t.Genre_Id);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Genres",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }
```

You can see it's added the extra `Genre_Id` property and set it as the foreign key.

Why has this happened? And how do I fix it? It took my a while to notice so I have several more migrations since this one, do I run down through them all, fix this (somehow), and back up through them again? Is it easier to just manually change it on the database? Or give up and use that field now as the foreign key?

Comment: Your GenreId is `byte` - it should be `int`. So EF created it's own `int`.

Comment: I did wonder about that, but it's byte in the tutorial, I also have byte used in other models (also following the tutorial) and it works fine and didn't generate an extra property.

Comment: Here's what EF did when I added a byte foreign key to another model:              AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", c => c.Byte(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", "dbo.MembershipTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);

Comment: The primary key of Genres is `int`. Was the primary key `int` in those other scenarios?

Comment: Ok, confirmed primary key is byte in the MembershipType model. So I guess that explains it...any idea how I fix it? Do I just change the Id to byte in the Genre model and run another migration? Or should I delete it, run a migration to drop the table, then re-add it? Btw please post response as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SteveGreene you solved my problem, would be great if you could post comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When entity framework can't automatically figure out a relationship, it adds a field like XXXXX_Id#. In Entity Framework, the foreign key's data type must match the data type of the entity you are relating to, so even though the name follows the convention it is not used. See [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions) for relationship conventions.